# Not able to play audio file in python

Tags: python, pygame, python-playsound

I am trying to play the audio files using Python. Below is my code:

```
from pygame import mixer
from time import sleep
from playsound import playsound

mixer.init()
# mixer.music.load("test1.mp3")
# mixer.music.play()
# sleep(1)
playsound("test.mp3")
```

I tried 2 methods to play audio:

1. playsound
2. pygames

with both the methods I was able to play the below mentioned audio.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-QQmMJnaK20L47DZGZS0MGZHnMK1uxdL/view?usp=sharing (filename is welcome5.mp3)--> able to play

but was not able to play the below audio given below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mh8iMM026aSKaBD2iEUB9R5dceRcNa4w/view?usp=sharing (file name is test.mp3)

With playsound I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\SANKETH\PycharmProjects\Practice\Files\tests\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    playsound("test.mp3")
  File "C:\Users\SANKETH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\SANKETH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 277 for command:
        open "test.mp3" alias playsound_0.8194752932436311
    A problem occurred in initializing MCI.
```

in case of pygame I am getting the below error:

```
Note: Illegal Audio-MPEG-Header 0x00000000 at offset 2650.
Note: Trying to resync...
Note: Skipped 10 bytes in input.
[d:\build\libmpg123\mpg123-1.25.10\src\libmpg123\layer1.c:30] error: Illegal bit allocation value.
[d:\build\libmpg123\mpg123-1.25.10\src\libmpg123\layer1.c:174] error: Aborting layer I decoding after step one.
```

below are the details of the libraries or packages installed from pip:

```
$ pip3 list|grep -i "playsound"
playsound                           1.2.2

SANKETH@DESKTOP-ULOB0S7 MINGW64 ~/PycharmProjects/Practice/Files/tests (master)
$ pip3 list|grep -i "pygame"
pygame                              1.9.6

names of the files:
$ ls -l|grep -i "test"
-rw-r--r-- 1 SANKETH 197121 9661986 Aug 31 02:55 test.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 SANKETH 197121     183 Aug 31 21:18 test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 SANKETH 197121    1772 Aug 30 22:32 test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 SANKETH 197121   58890 Aug 31 03:14 test1.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code in my local machine and it works totally fine to run this script all you need is to install pygame and playsound using pip

```
pip install pygame
pip install playsound
```

after that you need to change an mp3 file to name test.mp3 >> (when I try this in my local windows machine as "test.mp3" it doesn't work then I changed it to "test" then it started working )

I think you better check with the file name in Linux I think you should use the cli for listing the file name

Comment: Not sure how it worked on your local, i have updated my question in the last line i have given the details of the packages(playsound and pygame)  that i have already installed via pip, i can say that file is named test.mp3 which is as expected. Guess i have already tried whatever you are suggesting

Comment: Please look at the last part of the question that i have updated, i have already installed all the packages via pip and file is already named test.mp3

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try writing the whole path leading to the file for example if the file is on the c drive write
`playsound("c:/users/alex/desktop/test.mp3")`